# setOnClickListener not working for PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-settings

What I have is a `CheckBoxPreference` and an `EditTextPreference` within the Android Settings menu. What I want to do is uncheck the `CheckBox` when the `EditTextPreference` is clicked. Everything works fine unless I try to add the listener. It appears the problem starts with a null "custFragment." The app just crashes. Here is the code:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_search_method"
        android:key="prefSearchMethodSettings"
        android:layout="@layout/preferences_header_category">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="@string/use_menu"
            android:key="SHOWMENU"
            android:defaultValue="1">
        </CheckBoxPreference>

        <EditTextPreference
            android:title="@string/use_keyword"
            android:key="KEYWORD"
            android:summary="@string/use_keyword_summary"
            android:defaultValue="@string/settings_keyword_default">
        </EditTextPreference>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Java

```
package com.triunedev.foodeze;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.util.Log;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    SettingsFragment custFragment;
    EditTextPreference textPref;
    CheckBoxPreference checkPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment(), "fragTag").commit();

        custFragment = (SettingsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragTag");
        textPref = (EditTextPreference) custFragment.findPreference("KEYWORD");
        checkPref = (CheckBoxPreference) custFragment.findPreference("SHOWMENU");

        textPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                checkPref.setChecked(false);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and...

```
package com.triunedev.foodeze;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    public SettingsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

}
```

Please, where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `custFragment` is null.

you need to add the `fragment` to the `backstack` also during transaction.

Replace your code with:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment, "fragTag");
ft.addToBackStack("fragTag");
ft.commit();
fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

Now reuse the fragment using:

```
custFragment = (SettingsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragTag");
```

**EDIT**

To Resolve problem in your Back button: override `onBackPressed()` in your `SettingsActivity` and add the following code:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
       getFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    else super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: That works great for my purposes, but it appears it causes the back button to go to a blank screen on the first click, and then to the main activity on the second. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I tried that fix to no avail. I also tried to play with the parameters but still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: it will be better if u post a new question regarding the problem...so everybody can give suggestion..